# Is it safe to print a url verified with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL?

Tags: php

Is it safe to provide a GET variable called forward_url where they can set a url to send the page to 5 seconds after loading with a meta redirect?  Is it safe to print the URL to the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you're sanitizing it using:

```
$safeToOutputOnHtmlPage = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

it's safe

Answer (score 1):

well if your validation of the url returns invalid it will return as false. so if its a valid url then I guess in a way you should be safe.

Now would I do it? probably not. I would sanitize it before outputting it myself found here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

That will help get rid of nasties that people try to do